# Why is potassium permanganate coloured?

Tags: coordination-compounds, oxidation-state

$\ce{Mn}$ in  $\ce{KMnO4}$ is in $+7$ oxidation state, has no d electrons so  d-d transition is not possible.

Then, how is $\ce{KMnO4}$ coloured?

Comment: It is not ionic bond; there is still $\mathrm d$ electrons.

Comment: In $\ce{MnO4-}$, there are no electrons in the $e$ or $t_2$ orbitals which arise from the metal 3d orbitals and therefore what are conventionally known as d-d transitions are not possible. Whether it is ionic or covalent has no impact.